# java sockets UDP bidirectional using datagram

Tags: java, sockets, datagram

I am new to java sockets, I am trying to create a simple UDP transmission using client-server. My problem now is the server is running the infinite loop and not sending message over to the client. Sorry if i did some stupid mistake, thanks

Server:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


class EchoServer {

  public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception {

    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(54373);
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(new byte[512],512);
    String temp = "Hello client";
    byte[] buffer = temp.getBytes();

    while (true) {
      socket.receive( packet );
      System.out.println("Received from client");

      DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),54373);
      socket.send( packet2 );
    }   
  }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;


class EchoClient {
  public static void main( String args[] ) throws Exception {
    DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
    socket.setSoTimeout( 5000 );
    byte[] buffer = "Hello Server".getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer,buffer.length,InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"),54373);
    socket.send( packet );

    DatagramPacket packet2 = new DatagramPacket(new byte[512],512);
    socket.receive(packet2);
    System.out.println("Received from server");
  }
}
```

However, my server is able to send the original "packet" instead of packet2

Answer (score 0):

Your server is sending back to itself. Instead of using its own port number when constructing the reply datagram, it should use the one that's already in the request datagram. And the IP address. In fact it should just send the request datagram as-is, as it's an echo server: no need to construct another one.

If the protocol changes the idea is to use the `setData()` method on the request to put the reply into it, again rather than creating a new datagram.